# Streaming microphone audio from iPhone to outside server

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, microphone

I've seen questions on here about this, but no can't find any solutions.  Does anyone have a push in the right direction for streaming audio picked up from the mic to a server?  Like a one-way walkie talkie.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a combination of `AVCaptureSession` and `AVCaptureDevice` to read from the microphone - see the AV Foundation Programming Guide.

Then once you've got the data you'll need to stream it up to a server. Use TCP/IP sockets (see the CFNetwork Programming Guide).

Then just read the mic data, optionally transform it (compress, bit rate etc) and push it down the socket.

Comment: do you know, in wich format audio block are arriving in captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:? is it PCM? all the blocks have equal size of 2088 bytes. is it possible somehow to require certain compression like AAC or other?

Comment: Yes, you get 16-Bit PCM samples by default